# Adding a table to a div

Tags: html, html-table, tabs

I am completely new to html and I need some help.

I am looking to add a table 4x6 inside of a div. I am using code to generate tabs and basically each tab would have a table on it where I can add hyperlinks in a list. There are a lot of links so I figured 6 columns would make it easier to read without having to scroll down through one giant list in 1 column.

Any help would be appreciated as I am totally new to this

```html
  <meta charset="utf-8" unselectable="on">
  <title unselectable="on">jQuery UI Tabs - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" unselectable="on">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" unselectable="on"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js" unselectable="on"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" unselectable="on">
  <script unselectable="on">
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
  </script>


 
<div id="tabs" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" unselectable="on">
  <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" role="tablist" unselectable="on">
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tabs-1" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" aria-selected="true" aria-expanded="true" unselectable="on"><a href="#tabs-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1" unselectable="on">General Links</a></li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tabs-2" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" unselectable="on"><a href="#tabs-2" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-2" unselectable="on">xerox.com Resources</a></li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tabs-3" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" unselectable="on"><a href="#tabs-3" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-3" unselectable="on">Marketing and Sales Tools</a></li>
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tabs-4" aria-labelledby="ui-id-4" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" unselectable="on"><a href="#tabs-4" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-4" unselectable="on">Canadian Sales</a></li>
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tabs-5" aria-labelledby="ui-id-5" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" unselectable="on"><a href="#tabs-5" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-5" unselectable="on">Admin Support &amp; Training</a></li>
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tabs-6" aria-labelledby="ui-id-6" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" unselectable="on"><a href="#tabs-6" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-6" unselectable="on">Virtual Tools</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false" unselectable="on">
    <p unselectable="on">Test1 Test2 Test3 Test4 Test5</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;" unselectable="on">
    <p unselectable="on">Test2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;" unselectable="on">
    <p unselectable="on">Test3</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-4" aria-labelledby="ui-id-4" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;" unselectable="on">
    <p unselectable="on">Test4</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-5" aria-labelledby="ui-id-5" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;" unselectable="on">
    <p unselectable="on">Test5</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-6" aria-labelledby="ui-id-6" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;" unselectable="on">
    <p unselectable="on">Test6</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add `<table>...</table`> tags, that should get you started on the table.
With in the table, if you want to add headers, add `<th>...</th>` tags, that defines table headers. If not, you can just start on the rows by `<tr>...</tr>`

Numbers of columns are defined by number of `<td>...</td>` tags within th or tr...

```html
  <meta charset="utf-8" unselectable="on">
  <title unselectable="on">jQuery UI Tabs - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" unselectable="on">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" unselectable="on"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js" unselectable="on"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" unselectable="on">
  <script unselectable="on">
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
  </script>


 
<div id="tabs" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" unselectable="on">
  <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" role="tablist" unselectable="on">
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tabs-1" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" aria-selected="true" aria-expanded="true" unselectable="on"><a href="#tabs-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1" unselectable="on">General Links</a></li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tabs-2" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" unselectable="on"><a href="#tabs-2" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-2" unselectable="on">xerox.com Resources</a></li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tabs-3" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" unselectable="on"><a href="#tabs-3" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-3" unselectable="on">Marketing and Sales Tools</a></li>
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tabs-4" aria-labelledby="ui-id-4" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" unselectable="on"><a href="#tabs-4" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-4" unselectable="on">Canadian Sales</a></li>
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tabs-5" aria-labelledby="ui-id-5" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" unselectable="on"><a href="#tabs-5" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-5" unselectable="on">Admin Support &amp; Training</a></li>
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tabs-6" aria-labelledby="ui-id-6" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" unselectable="on"><a href="#tabs-6" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-6" unselectable="on">Virtual Tools</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false" unselectable="on">
    <p unselectable="on">Test1 Test2 Test3 Test4 Test5</p>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>test1</td>
            <td>test1</td>
            <td>test1</td>
            <td>test1</td>
            <td>test1</td>
            <td>test1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>test2</td>
            <td>test2</td>
            <td>test2</td>
            <td>test2</td>
            <td>test2</td>
            <td>test2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>test3</td>
            <td>test3</td>
            <td>test3</td>
            <td>test3</td>
            <td>test3</td>
            <td>test3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>test4</td>
            <td>test4</td>
            <td>test4</td>
            <td>test4</td>
            <td>test4</td>
            <td>test4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;" unselectable="on">
    <p unselectable="on">Test2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;" unselectable="on">
    <p unselectable="on">Test3</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-4" aria-labelledby="ui-id-4" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;" unselectable="on">
    <p unselectable="on">Test4</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-5" aria-labelledby="ui-id-5" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;" unselectable="on">
    <p unselectable="on">Test5</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-6" aria-labelledby="ui-id-6" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;" unselectable="on">
    <p unselectable="on">Test6</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that is a great start but I think I screwed something up. I am adding this to a sharepoint 2013 code snippet webpart and it all goes well until I add anything after Tab 3   it doesn't save and appears to throws a ERR_BLOCKED_BY_XSS_AUDITOR error. Is there a way I can attach my code as a txt document on here  - it is 32 pages. I have gone through it and it looks like every section is the same to me

Comment: @Mindbender I am not sure how you can attach it here. You can use like pastebin or something... as for the error, i think you might want to check if cookies are being passed correctly. If the site has CSRF enabled, you have to add that header in your POST requests. If all the cookies are there and being sent in each request, then we'd have to take a look at the code further.

Comment: I got the code to work....there were some errors in it that I found. I only get the error now when I try to look at the design view of the webpart. Would I just put that header at the top of the code?

Comment: @Mindbender is it still the same error you're getting? If it's not custom code for making a POST request, SP should handle everything on its own. Can you look at the developer tools for network logs and console logs to see if you see anything out of the ordinary please?

Comment: I do not have access to those tool so the logs. The page opens fine and I can edit the page and edit the snippet code but when I try to edit the content viewer webpart that contains the code it throws the error

Answer (score 0):

First time answering on here, so I'm not sure how to make it pretty, but you can add a table with the "table" tag, if you want headers there is a "th" tag, "tr" for each table row and "td" for table data aka each cell. You can do hyperlinks with the "a" tag and a href. I slapped together a quick example below, but it doesn't like when I try to format it the way I normally do.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><a href="www.google.com">Goes to Google</a></td>
<td><a href="www.yahoo.com">Goes to Yahoo</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="www.bing.com">Goes to Bing</a></td>
<td><a href="www.stackoverflow.com">Goes to Stack Overflow</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```